# VSTSDK and Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am new to C++ and Visual Studio and have two questions:

Where do I need to put the VSTSDK so that VS recognizes it and I can use it in my projects?

Does anybody have some sample code for a VST host?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter where you put the VST SDK, as long as you tell Visual Studio. In Visual Studio, you can add any library and #include path, and that's what you'll need from the SDK.

Comment: Right click on the Project :
Config. Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

You could also do it in Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories > Include Files. That way you can add the include folder for all of your projects.

Comment: +1 for @3nixios. You'd choose the first (per-project) setting if you plan to make one or a few VST projects, and the second if that's your main use of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend checking out the [Audacity Source Code](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/beta_source) for a VST hosting example. There used to be a great vsthost.cpp example on the web, too, but I can't seem to find it. =/

Answer (score 0):

There are some few examples like, vsthost, vstboard, audacity.
vsthost is using asio only, the 2 others are using portaudio and portmidi.

vstboard is using Qt for gui, audacity uses wxwidget.

The problem is : what kind of host do you need (simple for one plug in ora complex one) Also, you should take a look at JUCE library which offers good features for all of that even if I would prefer the vstboard design (Qt + portaudio)

good luck